# Convert text to HTML comment in Python

Tags: python, markdown, html

I have a Python script that generates some HTML. It does so using [the Python markdown library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown). I'd like to stick the original Markdown text in a comment at the end of the HTML, where it will occasionally be useful for debugging purposes. I've tried just plunking the Markdown text after the end of the HTML, and it doesn't work for me (Firefox). So the way I imagine this working is that I run Markdown and then simply append the Markdown source, marked as a comment, after the HTML. However, HTML is apparently somewhat finicky about what it will allow in comments. The site htmlhelp.com gives the following advice after some discussion:

> For this reason, use the following simple rule to compose valid and accepted [portable] comments:
>       An HTML comment begins with "" and does not contain "--" or ">" anywhere in the comment.
>   [(source)](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/wilbur/misc/comment.html)

So it looks like I need to do some escaping or something to get my bunch of markdown text into a form that HTML will accept as a comment. Is there an existing tool that will help me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#comments):

```
Comments consist of the following parts, in exactly the following order:

- the comment start delimiter "<!--"
- text
- the comment end delimiter "-->"

The text part of comments has the following restrictions:

1. must not start with a ">" character
2. must not start with the string "->"
3. must not contain the string "--"
4. must not end with a "-" character
```

These are very simple rules. You could regex-enforce them, but they are so simple you don't even need that!

3 of the 4 conditions can be met with concatenation, and the other one with a simple `replace()`. **All in all, it's a one-liner**:

```
def html_comment(text):
    return '<!-- ' + text.replace('--', '- - ') + ' -->'
```

Note the spaces.

Comment: Not the first time the solution to a problem I posted was embarassingly simple. There were a couple weird cases like `'---'.replace('--', '- -') == '- --'`  that your code wasn't handling quite how I wanted (still two hyphens in a row), so I'm currently using `'<!-- ' + text.replace('--', '_-_-_').replace('>', '&gt;') + ' -->'` instead

Comment: So in the end, it wasn't so simple :) I'll update the answer to reflect your change. If this is what you end up using, consider marking it as accepted as well, for the benefit of future readers

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just `.replace` it?  Ultimately, you could replace those characters with *anything*, but substituting with escape codes probably won't make your comment any more readible than substituting with nothing.

```
commented = '<!-- %s -->' % markdown_text.replace('--', '').replace('>', '')
```